# Can I charge a simple Nokia phone which has USB input (5V=450mA) with a 5V=2A/7V=1.8A/9V=1.8A/12V=1.3A supply?

Tags: usb, battery, charging

I have a Nokia Asha 501 Dual Sim phone which comes with the power supply as stated in the title. It recently broke, and I decided to test if the phone's USB port which I thought was only for data transfer will act as supply as well. It did, surprisingly for me. I have 3 chargers, one is an original firm charger from another device and others is cheap ones. The original one and one of cheap ones has 5V=2A and other cheap one is all from the question title (except 5V=450mA).
I observed how they all charge the phone, and the cheap ones make the phone glitchy and heat the charger extremely fast. The original one seemingly charger fine, no extreme heat ups or glitches of the phone.
However, are the supply specs itself safe? Will they fry the phone eventually and/or something?

Comment: If this is off-topic, [why this isn't?](https://superuser.com/questions/600401/can-i-use-a-charger-with-more-output-amperage-than-the-device-needs/600426#600426)

Comment: @grawity depends how you look at it, USB isn't unique to computers. Either way, this is either off-topic, or a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

You can fry the phone with a voltage too high, or inversed polarity. If the charger provides 2A, but the phone only needs 450mA, there's no problem. The charger heating, maybe the phone draws more than the charger can provide.